# deployd login related error when deployed in Heroku

Tags: heroku, deployd

I am getting this error when I deploy deployd app in heroku. In local envinronment it works just okay. It is happening from deployd source code and I cannot figure out why. I assume that it might be something with user object but when I see it from local environment, it looks just okay. Unfortunately I could not figure out a way to hack heroku to have a deep look on a node_module level.. user collection has been copied manually along with password hash from local. Anyone has a clue? much appreciated.

UserCollection.getUserAndPasswordHash at /app/node_modules/deployd/lib/resources/user-collection.js:291:35

```
<body>
  <div class="container-full text-center">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Username</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
              </div>
          <button type="submit" id="signin" class="btn btn-info">Sign In</button>
        </form>
        </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/lib/toastr.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/dpd.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    dpd.users.me(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        location.href = "/assets.html";
      }
    });

    $('#signin').click(function() {
      var username = $('#username').val();
      var password = $('#password').val();

      dpd.users.login({username: username, password: password}, function(session, error) {
        if (error) {
          toastr.error(error.message);
        } else {
          location.href = "/assets.html";
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

----- error ------

> TypeError: Data must be a string or a buffer
>   2017-10-26T19:31:10.868780+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Hash.update
>   (crypto.js:99:16) 2017-10-26T19:31:10.868781+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   UserCollection.getUserAndPasswordHash
>   (/app/node_modules/deployd/lib/resources/user-collection.js:291:35)
>   2017-10-26T19:31:10.868782+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   /app/node_modules/deployd/lib/resources/user-collection.js:308:27
>   2017-10-26T19:31:10.868783+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   /app/node_modules/deployd/lib/db.js:412:11
>   2017-10-26T19:31:10.868784+00:00 app[web.1]:     at handleCallback
>   (/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:120:56)
>   2017-10-26T19:31:10.868784+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   /app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cursor.js:861:16
>   2017-10-26T19:31:10.868785+00:00 app[web.1]:     at handleCallback
>   (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:171:5)
>   2017-10-26T19:31:10.868785+00:00 app[web.1]:     at setCursorNotified
>   (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:515:3)
>   2017-10-26T19:31:10.868786+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   /app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:597:16
>   2017-10-26T19:31:10.868787+00:00 app[web.1]:     at queryCallback
>   (/app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/cursor.js:232:18)
>   2017-10-26T19:31:10.868787+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   /app/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:469:18
>   2017-10-26T19:31:10.868788+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7) 2017-10-26T19:31:10.868788+00:00 app[web.1]:     at
>   process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:218:9)
>   2017-10-26T19:31:10.874754+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13
>   desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET
>   path="/assets1.html" host=mineralmarket.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=6e2be40a-8043-46ff-ae8b-f923e8c59b06 fwd="220.76.173.176"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=52ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https

Comment: Looks like you tried to hash a null value.Can you check in your network monitor in browser if username and password was successfully passed in request?

Comment: it worked after cleaning up the brower cache.. still not sure why it happened...but it works okay now..